# Embedding native win32 resources into .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, resources, mmc

Is it possible to embed a .net resource (resx) into compiled assembly as a native win32 resource? Like I need an array of native resource images writing my MMC custom snap-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can still embed standard rc/RES files into compiled assemblies, just like you do on a native binary